# Java - Hangman game with StringBuilder. Catching multiple letters in a word

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I'm just a beginner in coding and trying to make my 1st project with several classes that is a hangman game. I know there are a lot of threads on the topic here but couldn't manage to find a solution that would work with StringBuilder.  I'm stuck with catching multiple letters in the word. Could anyone possibly help?
the method under question is checkAnswer and is below:

```
public void checkAnswer (){
    if (logic.line.indexOf(answer)!= -1){
    System.out.println ("You are right! The letter " + answer + " exists");
    StringBuilder guessedChar = new StringBuilder(logic.newLine);
    guessedChar.setCharAt(logic.line.indexOf(answer), answer);
    lettersGuessed = answer +lettersGuessed;
            score = score + 1;
            System.out.println("Letters guessed: " + lettersGuessed);
            System.out.println("Letters missed: " + lettersMissed);
            System.out.println("Your score is:" + score);
   logic.newLine = guessedChar.toString();
    System.out.println(logic.newLine);
        }}
```

Below is the full code:
main class
    public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Logic act = new Logic();
    Game game = new Game();
    act.getListOfMovies();
    act.CodedLine();
    do { game.input();
    game.checkCondition();
            game.checkAnswer();
            game.checkScore();
    } while (game.lettersGuessed.length() != act.line.length() && game.score!= -10);
}}
```

Class Logic

```
public class Logic {
static String line;
static String newLine;
public String[] listOfMovies;
public Scanner fileScanner;

public Logic() {
}

public String getListOfMovies() throws Exception {
    File fileWithMovies = new File("MoviesList.txt");//file access
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileWithMovies);//file scan
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) { // while there is a next line
        line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        String[] listOfMovies = new String[24];  //introduce array
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfMovies.length; i++) { //
            listOfMovies[i] = fileScanner.nextLine();
        } 
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * listOfMovies.length);  //get random number
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {             //get random movie
            if (Character.isLetter(line.charAt(i))) {
                line = listOfMovies[random];
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            return line;
        }
        return line;
    }return line;
}



public String CodedLine() {
    newLine = line.replaceAll("[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z]", "_");
    System.out.println(newLine);
    return newLine;
}}
```

Class Game

```
public class Game {
char answer;
Logic logic = new Logic();
String lettersGuessed = " ";
String lettersMissed = " ";
int score = 0;


public char input () {
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in your guess");
    answer = inputScanner.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Your guess: " + answer);
    return answer;
    }
public void checkCondition (){
if (logic.line.indexOf(answer)==-1){
    System.out.println("You are wrong. The letter " + answer + " does not exist");
    lettersMissed = answer + lettersMissed;
    score = score - 1;
    System.out.println("Letters guessed: " + lettersGuessed);
    System.out.println("Letters missed: " + lettersMissed);
    System.out.println("Your score is:" + score);
}}

public void checkAnswer (){
    if (logic.line.indexOf(answer)!= -1){
    System.out.println ("You are right! The letter " + answer + " exists");
    StringBuilder guessedChar = new StringBuilder(logic.newLine);
    guessedChar.setCharAt(logic.line.indexOf(answer), answer);
    lettersGuessed = answer +lettersGuessed;
            score = score + 1;
            System.out.println("Letters guessed: " + lettersGuessed);
            System.out.println("Letters missed: " + lettersMissed);
            System.out.println("Your score is:" + score);
   logic.newLine = guessedChar.toString();
    System.out.println(logic.newLine);
        }}

public void checkScore (){
    if (score == -10) {
        System.out.println("The game is over! You lost..."); }}}
```

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: methods are written in camelCase. Also, you should properly indent your code, as it will make it better readable to others *and* yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Create list for index 
ArrayList<Integer>answerIndexList=new ArrayList<Integer>();


//get char index
for (int i=0;i<logic.line.length();i++){
    if(logic.line.charAt(i) == answer){
        answerIndexList.add(i);
     }
}


//replace index with answer
for(int i=0;i<answerIndexList.size();i++){

    guessedChar.setCharAt(answerIndexList.get(i), answer);
}

logic.newLine = guessedChar.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not gonna solve it for you, not what this site is for, but suggestions:

1. [check this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) - basically you tell it where the `indexOf` should start searching. At first you start with `0`, then if you find a result you start at `foundResultIndex + 1`, put it all in a loop and voila.

```java
word: batman, guess: a

int startAt = 0;

int foundResultIndex = "batman".indexOf('a', startAt) // 1

startAt = foundResultIndex + 1;

foundResultIndex = "batman".indexOf('a', startAt) // 4

...
```

2. don't keep so much state in your programs, especially static like in `Logic` class. Your `getListOfMovies` is perfect example, you are already returning a result, why keep it in some `line` variable? Use the returned result instead.
3. the `replaceAll` is funny, do this instead `line.replaceAll("[a-z]", "_");`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable notes about the code! As for the loop I had tried doing that way as read in the book, that resulted in the right number of repeating letters but didn't add them to the stock of found letters. Probably did smth wrong - going to go over it again and find out how it works! Thank for the advice once more!